# How to know which files iTunes could not import?

Tags: itunes, file, import

I'm trying to import a large iTunes library from an XML file, but at the end I get a message:

> Some songs of "example.xml" file were not imported because they were not found

However, I know that all the songs in the XML really exist (since I've generated it a few minutes before), so how can I know which songs iTunes didn't import? Is there maybe a log somewhere I could look at?

Comment: I do not know about the log, but using simple sort by (date, name ect.) on both sides, you can see which one is downloaded and which one is not.

Comment: Can you diff songs in "recently added" section vs. the song list you are importing and see what is missing?  You should be able to export them in a variety of formats from iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that importing songs with ampersands and commas in their title or album name can cause problems.  I haven't found a workaround, but exporting the library to a text file and then searching the proper columns might help identify the missing files.